# controling size of Bubble chart's circle using googleVis in R

Tags: r, googlevis

I did it using `googleVis`

```
> library(googleVis)

> trees2<-trees

>trees2$id<-as.character(1:31)

> Bubble<-gvisBubbleChart(trees2,idvar="id",xvar="Girth",yvar="Height",sizevar="Volume",options=list(vAxis="{title:'height'}",hAxis="{title:'Girth'}"))

> plot(Bubble)
```

and I had a chart but the circles are too large;;

Is there a way to control the size of the circle just like the symbols function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sizeAxis` option

```
library(googleVis    
trees2<-trees    
trees2$id<-as.character(1:31)    
Bubble<-gvisBubbleChart(trees2, idvar="id", xvar="Girth" ,yvar="Height",sizevar="Volume"
                        , options=list(vAxis="{title:'height'}",hAxis="{title:'Girth'}", sizeAxis = '{minValue: 0,  maxSize: 10}'))    
plot(Bubble)
```

Full list of options are given [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart?hl=ja#Configuration_Options).

[image: buuble chart]